# How to use a segue, programmatically, in a UIViewController of a PageViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue, uipageviewcontroller

I have 3 view controllers used in a PageViewController.

I am using the following code to navigate from one view controller to another view controller:

```
 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goHome", sender: self)
```

The segue navigates to the view controller I want, however it is not embedded in the PageViewController. How can I page between view controllers programmatically?

**EDIT**
I am trying to trigger this event by click of a button (in addition to the swipes that already work), or after completion of certain user triggered events. This is why I would like to understand how to do this through a segue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

UIPageViewController has `gestureRecognizers` property, which are pre-configured to handle user interaction, it also has `viewControllers` property, all you need to do is implement `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` protocol methods, providing a controller when user swipe the view, and it will work automatically.